# Need to SUM the total amount of a sub query

Tags: sql

I would love if someone could help me on this. Got a query that does a subquery that sums the amount of replicates, so now i have the sample mother, the amount of replicates , and the samples that belong to the mother. Right now I have this :

```
select s.sample_number,(SELECT SUM(rep) as replicates
                        FROM (SELECT ts.sample_number, MAX(ts.replicate_count) - 1  as rep
                                from test ts
                                where ts.sample_number = s1.sample_number
                                GROUP BY ts.sample_number, ts.analysis) A 
                        GROUP BY sample_number),s1.sample_number
from sample s
JOIN sample s1 ON s.sample_number = s1.parent_aliquot
where s.parent_aliquot = 0 
order by s.sample_number DESC
```

Here's what the query shows :

[image]

What I need is only the number of the mother sample and the total amount of replicates for each mother sample.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a new question.  Clearly describe the problem you are trying to solve.  Provide sample data and desired results *as text tables in the question*.  Tag the question with the database you are using.  And also include your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to JOIN to the results of your subquery rather than have them in the SELECT, and include the sample number in that subquery to JOIN on.

Getting a bit confusing without having the tables to test on, but maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
s.sample_number as mother_sample_number
,SUM(reps.replicates) as replicates_for_mother

from sample s
JOIN sample s1 ON s.sample_number = s1.parent_aliquot
JOIN (  SELECT sample_number, SUM(rep) as replicates
        FROM (  SELECT ts.sample_number, MAX(ts.replicate_count) - 1  as rep
                from test ts
                --where ts.sample_number = s1.sample_number
                GROUP BY ts.sample_number, ts.analysis
             ) A 
        GROUP BY sample_number
    ) reps on reps.sample_number = s1.sample_number

where s.parent_aliquot = 0 
order by s.sample_number DESC
```